# How can I change an extension's icon?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want to change the icons of some extensions I've installed.

I have looked in Chrome's `AppData` folder, but I just found some `.sql` files.

Where does Chrome locally store extension icons?

Comment: This has two sides: **1.** Do you want to manipulate the icons of 3rd party extensions you install? **2.** Do you want to know how to add an icon to the extension you're making (so users see the icon at install)?

Comment: Have a look, http://lifehacker.com/5801293/customize-extension-icons-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome extensions are stored in
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`.

The icons of the extensions should be inside the extensions' folders (the names for the folders aren't readable, so you need to go one by one or search the name of the extension to get to its folder):

[image: Chrome Extensions' folders]

Look for `.png` files located either in the main extension folder or inside a subfolder named "images", "pictures", "icons" or something along those lines. Sometimes there are multiple sizes for an icon (usually 16, 32, 48 and 128) so you might need to change them all.

Comment: As of Chrome 72 this is now in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions`.

Answer (score 0):

Converting @Lamb's comment to an answer:

Lifehacker has a tutorial [here](http://lifehacker.com/5801293/customize-extension-icons-in-google-chrome).

#### Quick Tutorial

The extension files can be found in:

- Windows Vista/7/8: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`
- Windows 2000/XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`

Find the ID of the extension you want to change, by searching the name you want in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home), then clicking on it.

The ID will be in the URL: `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail/pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia` (the ID is **pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia**).

Switch back to Explorer, and enter the folder that matches the extension's ID.

The mainifest.json file will list the extension's icon files. You can replace those.